# Uncaught Reference Error using Webpack (HTML Webpack plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I have a class called "Widget" in widget.js. It has the following code:

```
export class Widget {

    constructor(elem,data) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.data = data;


    }

    init(){
        ......
    }
}
```

I then have an index.js file, with the following code:

```
import { Widget as defaultExport } from './lib/widget';

export default defaultExport;
```

Using Webpack, this index.js file is linked to a HTML file, index.html. Now, I have a script tag in my HTML page which tries to import the Widget class and call the init function in the class. I have been trying to do the following

```
<script>


        $(document).ready(function() {

            console.log("In document ready" );
            let instance = new Widget(element,"data");
            instance.init();

        });

    </script>
```

My motive is to import the Widget class in the HTML file through the index.js, and call the init method. When I try to execute this, I get an "Uncaught Reference Error : Widget not found". I tried using "`new defaultExport`" instead of `new Widget`, which also does not work. I also tried `"import Widget from 'index.js'"`, which gives me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier". I tried setting script type to "module", and it does not execute the jquery block (please see the following block):

```
 <script type="module">

        import Widget from './src/index'
        $(document).ready(function() {

            console.log("In document ready" );
            let instance = new Widget(element,"data");
            instance.init();

        });

    </script>
```

Could you please help me solve this

Edit : I noticed in the Elements section of the developer console that the script import tag to the index.js file is being added after the  tag I have in the HTML file(Please see below). Could that be the reason for this Reference error?

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
..........
</script>
<script src = '/index.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [output.library](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary) configuration.

> Output a library exposing the exports of your entry point.

E.g.

Project structure:

```
$ tree -L 2 -I node_modules
.
├── dist
│   ├── index.html
│   └── widget.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── index.js
│   └── widget.js
└── webpack.config.js

2 directories, 8 files
```

`src/index.js`:

```js
import { Widget as defaultExport } from './widget';

export default defaultExport;
```

`src/widget.js`:

```js
export class Widget {
    constructor(elem, data) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.data = data;
    }
    init() {
        console.log('Initialize widget success');
    }
}
```

`src/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="widget"></div>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      console.log("In document ready" );
      const element = document.getElementById('widget');
      let instance = new Widget(element, "data");
      instance.init();
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'widget.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true,
        library: {
            name: 'Widget',
            type: 'window',
            export: 'default',
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            minify: false,
        }),
    ],
};
```

Build logs:

```
> webpack

asset index.html 573 bytes [compared for emit]
asset widget.js 338 bytes [emitted] [minimized] (name: main)
runtime modules 396 bytes 2 modules
orphan modules 151 bytes [orphan] 1 module
./src/index.js + 1 modules 234 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 193 ms
```

**Output**

`dist/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
<script defer src="widget.js"></script></head>
<body>
  <div id="widget"></div>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      console.log("In document ready" );
      const element = document.getElementById('widget');
      let instance = new Widget(element, "data");
      instance.init();
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`dist/widget.js`:

```js
(() => {
    'use strict';
    var e = {
            d: (t, o) => {
                for (var i in o) e.o(o, i) && !e.o(t, i) && Object.defineProperty(t, i, { enumerable: !0, get: o[i] });
            },
            o: (e, t) => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, t),
        },
        t = {};
    e.d(t, { default: () => o });
    const o = class {
        constructor(e, t) {
            (this.elem = e), (this.data = t);
        }
        init() {
            console.log('Initialize widget success');
        }
    };
    window.Widget = t.default;
})();
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack",
        "start": "http-server ./dist"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
        "http-server": "^14.1.1",
        "webpack": "^5.80.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.0.2"
    }
}
```

Start an HTTP server to serve the `dist/index.html` file. Console logs of browser:

```
In document ready
Initialize widget success
```